# MySQL IF statement in UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Why cannot i use IF like this

```
UPDATE my_users
    IF(position2 = 18, "SET position = 17", ''),
    IF(position2 = 17, "SET position = 16", ''),
    IF(position2 = 16, "SET position = 15", ''),
        WHERE user_id => 170 AND user_id <= 1000
```

Only thing that works is

```
UPDATE my_users
    SET position2 = IF(position2 = 18, 17, 
                      IF(position2 = 17, 16, 
                        IF(position2 = 16, 15, ''
                      )
                        )
                          )
        WHERE user_id => 170 AND user_id <= 1000
```

is there way to make same thng in any other way because i have more than 40 conditions for that field position2 and its easy to get lost in this way?

**Edit:**

If i run

```
UPDATE my_users
    SET position2 = CASE position2  WHEN 18 THEN 17
                    WHEN 17 THEN 16
                    WHEN 16 THEN 15
                    END
            WHERE user_id => 170 AND user_id <= 1000
```

when `position2` is anything not in CASE statement it sets it to nothing, how can i just keep any value other than what in CASE statement the same

**Edit 2:**
I guess solution is:

```
   UPDATE my_users
        SET position2 = CASE position2  WHEN 18 THEN 17
                        WHEN 17 THEN 16
                        WHEN 16 THEN 15
                            ELSE position2
                        END
                WHERE user_id => 170 AND user_id <= 1000
```

**Edit 3:**
If my request was not one time thing the more faster request would be as suggested Vatev

```
   UPDATE my_users
        SET position2 = CASE position2  WHEN 18 THEN 17
                        WHEN 17 THEN 16
                        WHEN 16 THEN 15
                        END
                WHERE user_id => 170 AND user_id <= 1000
                AND position2 >= 16 and <= 18
```

Comment: Take a look at [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).

Comment: Btw if you want to decrement the column you can just `SET position2 = position2-1;`.

Comment: One more question i added to main post

Comment: just add ELSE clause, like ... `ELSE position2 END`. Or just update only those rows where position2 IN (16,17,18) with position2-1, it'd be better.

Comment: The proper way would be to add `AND position2 IN (16,17,18)` to your WHERE clause. You can also put a 'default' CASE like this `CASE position2 WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE position2 END`.

Comment: Thax raina77ow we posted at the same time heh.

Vatev can you explain why my way is not proper?

Comment: When you add `position2 IN (16,17,18)` you only update the rows you need and it might get faster and lock less rows if there is an index on position2.

Comment: Please stop changing and adding new questions to this one. If you have new questions, post them as new questions. Changing it repeatedly makes answering it like trying to hit a moving target. Thanks.

Comment: Ken White i dont see any "answers" here yet... 

Anyway thanks everyone you can close it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do something like this:

```
                UPDATE my_users
                     SET position2 = CASE WHEN position2 =18 THEN 17
                        WHEN position2 =17 THEN 16
                        WHEN position2 =16 THEN 15 ELSE position2 
                        END
                WHERE user_id between 170 AND  1000
                AND position2 between 16 and  18
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would rewrite your query:

```
UPDATE
  my_users
SET 
  position2 = position2 - 1
WHERE
  position2 >= 16
  AND position2 <= 18
  AND user_id >= 170 
  AND user_id <= 1000
```